# Understanding GoLang Profiling output

Tags: go, optimization, apache-kafka, profiling, sarama

Some context:

I'm trying to debug a GoGRPC server, a specific API call seems to take a lot of time. This call does a number of reads to Kafka(lets say 10-20) so I expected it to take some time, just not quite as much.

1 API call takes roughly 1-3 seconds to complete, but if i make 40 api calls in a script, it takes almost 30 seconds to complete all of them. but it doesnt complete them 'concurrently' as I expect, which is taking 5 seconds for the first one, and spit out 1 every second or so for later ones.

It takes 29 seconds and responds to all 40 requests at once. Which causes the API caller to timeout when the requests take too long.

I'm trying to profile the CPU to see where I'm spending the time. But I'm new to this and the outputs for the go profiler is not making a lot of sense.

I've generated diagrams with `go tool pprof`, but having some trouble interpreting the output.

CPU call graph

1. theres a box describing the time, type, buildID etc. the `Duration` in this box, is that describing the total time the CPU ran for? not including wiat time
2. there are 2 types of edges, solid lines, and dotted lines. what is the difference? and what does the time marked on the edges mean?
3. does the direction of the arrows mean calling direction? e.g. function A calls B, on the graph it will be A -> B?
4. each vertex have a time at the bottom e.g. 0.01s(0.93%) out of 0.49s(45.79%), what does this time mean?

block profile

1. same as #4 above, there is time on edges, and vertex. what does this mean?

EDIT:

I what my server does is retrieve some data from kafka streams. I've identified what was being slow, and I've wrote a script that only has the kafka calling functions. here's the script and block profiling diagram.

every consume to kafka takes about 50-100ms, but because most of the time is spent in doing IO, i expect the throughput of the API to be actually quite high, which is not the case. if i make 100 calls, it takes about 3 seconds, if i make 400 it takes about 10s. trying to see how i can speed out the throughput of the API

```
func main() {

    f, _ := os.Create("cpu.prof")
    pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
    defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()

    block, _ := os.Create("block.prof")
    runtime.SetBlockProfileRate(1)
    p := pprof.Lookup("block")
    defer p.WriteTo(block, 0)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(messageCount)
    for i := 0; i < messageCount; i++ {
        go func() {
            // consume()
            withConsumer()
            wg.Done()
        }()

    }

    wg.Wait()
}

var servers = []string{"kafka-1", "kafka-2", "kafka-3"}

var count = 0
var partition = int32(0)

func consume() {

    index := count
    t := time.Now()
    count++
    fmt.Println("starting consume", index)
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("consume ", index, "took", time.Since(t).String())
    }()

    consumer, err := sarama.NewConsumer(servers, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var max, min int64
    max = 1431401
    min = 2

    defer func() {
        consumer.Close()
    }()

    pc, err := consumer.ConsumePartition("source-topic", partition, rand.Int63n(max-min)+min)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        pc.Close()
    }()

    signals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signals, os.Interrupt)

    select {
    case msg := <-pc.Messages():
        fmt.Println("msg: ", len(msg.Value))
    case <-signals:
        return
    }
}
```

[image]
Thanks,

Comment: Possible to share the diagram?

Comment: Read https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs. Tip: _Always_ consult golang.org first as you'll find the answer there.

Comment: thanks, I found that link after i posted the question, that post also doesnt go into detail about how block profiller works. I will add more context to the question

Answer (score 0):

> 1. theres a box describing the time, type, buildID etc. the Duration in
>    this box, is that describing the total time the CPU ran for? not
>    including wiat time

Correct.  https://golang.org/doc/diagnostics#profiling says:

> cpu: CPU profile determines where a program spends its time while
> actively consuming CPU cycles (as opposed to while sleeping or waiting
> for I/O).

> 2. there are 2 types of edges, solid lines, and dotted lines. what is
>    the difference? and what does the time marked on the edges mean?

https://github.com/google/pprof/issues/493 says "Dotted/dashed lines indicated that that intervening nodes have been removed.   Nodes are removed to keep graphs small enough for visualization."

https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/cpuprofile.html says "Each edge is labelled with the time spent by the callee on behalf of the caller."

> 3. does the direction of the arrows mean calling direction? e.g.
>    function A calls B, on the graph it will be A -> B?

Yes.

> 4. each vertex have
>    a time at the bottom e.g. 0.01s(0.93%) out of
>    0.49s(45.79%), what does this time mean?

The first time is the local time.  The second time is the cumulative time.  https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/cpuprofile.html elaborates:

> The "local" time is the time spent executing the instructions directly
> contained in the procedure (and in any other procedures that were
> inlined into the procedure). The "cumulative" time is the sum of the
> "local" time and the time spent in any callees. If the cumulative time
> is the same as the local time, it is not printed.